# How do I get the index of an item in tkinter.Listbox?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

For example:

```
import tkinter as tk
x = tk.Tk()
y = tk.Listbox(x, bg="white")
y.insert(tk.END, "value1")
y.insert(tk.END, "value2")
>>>return y.index("value1")
```

This should output 0 but it just gives me an error, I did some reasearch and I can't find anything that has so I ask here.

Answer (score 10):

The `index` method of the listbox isn't the same as the `index` method of a python list. For the listbox, it translates something like "end" or "@x,y" into a numerical index.

To search, get the values as a python list, and then use the `index` method of the list:

```
index = y.get(0, "end").index("value1")
```

Comment: When I did what you said I got this error:
`ValueError: tuple.index(x): x not in tuple`

Comment: `y.get()` returns a `tuple`, so convert it to `list` first: `list(y.get(0, "end")).index("value1")`

Comment: @SergioLey-Languren: that means exactly what it says: the item you are looking for isn’t in the returned value.